# Choose ringtone from music library

Tags: 8.0, music, ringtone

[This page](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/add-ringtones-to-my-phone) describes how to add custom ringtones to a WP 8 device, but it's not very convenient to plug the phone to the computer every time I want to do this, especially when the music I want to use is already on the phone. Is there a way to choose a ringtone directly from the phone's music library? Or perhaps an app to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Nokia-exclusive app to do this: http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-releases-exclusive-windows-phone-app-ringtone-creation

Comment: Thanks! The app seems very buggy, can't find my songs alone (I have to get it through the album) and crashes very often, but I guess it's better than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If the ringtone is already on the phone, try this page....

[Ringtones, sounds and volume](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/ringtones-sounds-and-volume)

If you need some new ringtones, there are a few free apps in the store that provide some pretty cool ones. I won't plug them here, but they aren't hard to find.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help... the song I want to use is already on the phone, but it's in the music library, *not* in the ringtones.